# Javascript error in Google PHP/MySQL with Google Maps example

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to follow an example of Google Maps API Family called Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps ([Example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3.html)):

I thought this should be straight forward and that there should be some good discussion around it. Wrong! Most of it is straight forward, except the last part doesn't work and reports a Javascript error in the Chrome console.

I have the Outputting XML with PHP working: [link](http://www.japaneselifestyle.com.au/test/phpsqlajax_genxml2.php)

Now in the [final part](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles-phpsqlajax/phpsqlajax_map.htm), my code is the same except that I had to change the "phpsqlajax_genxml.php" for "phpsqlajax_genxml2.php".

The error report in Chrome console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] on line 34
Uncaught ReferenceError: load is not defined on line 84
```

But I can't find the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: is it possible to provide a demo of the issue?

Comment: line 34 from Google demo

Comment: compare line 34 from Google demo with yours for number of ] and have you a load function as asked for in line 84

Comment: if you just save and open the full "putting it all together" example from google and swap in his php xml generator, it gives the errors he mentions.

Comment: Use the code in [link](phpsqlajax_map_v3.html)                      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name"); not                    var name = markers[[]i].getAttribute("name");  etc

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your PHP script, but the code shown on Google's [page](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3.html) actually contains errors. In the downloadable sample [here](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles/phpsqlajax/phpsqlajax_map_v3.html), the errors are not present.

The problem is that the page on the Google page uses erroneous syntax to access array elements:

```
var name = markers[[]i].getAttribute("name");
var address = markers[[]i].getAttribute("address");
var type = markers[[]i].getAttribute("type");
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
  parseFloat(markers[[]i].getAttribute("lat")),
  parseFloat(markers[[]i].getAttribute("lng")));
var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
var icon = customIcons[[]type] || {};
```

The correct code is:

```
var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
  parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
  parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
```

Firebug reports:

```
Line 34: missing ] in index expression:
var name = markers[[]i].getAttribute("name");
```

which was actually more helpful than Chrome's syntax error report. Since your load() method thus contains an error, the entire method cannot be interpreted and so does not exist, which explains the second error you got.